# Server Error in '/' Application - SPO Provider Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, azure, office-365-developer

I have a Provider Hosted App in SharePoint online, and the app website is hosted Azure. When I'm browsing the site getting the below run time error.

[image]

[image]

I made the custom error mode off in web.config but still I'm unable to see the detailed error.
Can any one help me on how to see the detailed error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to the web.config for your site:

```
<compilation
     debug="true"
    />
```

You could also enable web server logging in the Azure portal for any clues:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-web-server-logging

Comment: Thanks for your response. As suggested added <compilation  debug="true" /> and also enable web server logging. Still not getting any detailed error info. It's working intermittently, some time page loads and some time server/error coming. Any further input on this kind of issue?